# Idiomatic ways of saying "As we talked about ..." / "Like I said ..." / etc

Tags: selección-de-palabras, modismos, idiomático

I am trying to determine how to best translate the English phrases *"Like I said [just now] ..."* or *"As we discussed [previously] ..."*, which indicate that what follows has already been said at some point in the past.

Por ejemplo:

> "**As we talked about yesterday**, the cows are not producing milk."
>
> *________?________, las vacas no producen leche.*
>
> "**Like we discussed Tuesday**, we should burn all of the documents."
>
> *________?________, deberíamos quemar todos de los documentos.*
>
> **Like I said** [just now], I don't want to buy your dirty socks.
>
> *________?________, no quiero comprar sus calcetines sucios.*

My first guess, attempting a direct translation was something like:
***"Como discutimos ayer ...", etc***. Is "como" the right word to use here for "as/like"? Are there more idiomatic/natural ways of expressing this in Spanish?

Comment: Likewise in English, in Spanish we have many, many ways to express this. The usage of one or another depends on the specific situation. If there was an agreement, _tal y como acordamos_; if it was a bit more informal, _tal y como dijimos_, and so on. So I am not sure if you are looking for a translation for a specific situation or you want a set of options.

Comment: fedorqui, Thank you. I figured there were probably many ways of expressing it in Spanish too, and was looking for a set of options (rather than just translations for a specific situation). In particular, I am interested in knowing which sound more "casual" and would be encountered more frequently in everyday speech, and which would sound more formal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the following translations are valid for each of your sentence:

> "As we talked about yesterday, the cows are not producing milk."

- *Como ya hablamos ayer*, las vacas no producen leche.

> "Like we discussed Tuesday, we should burn all of the documents."

- *Tal y como discutimos el martes,* deberíamos quemar todos los documentos.

> Like I said [just now], I don't want to buy your dirty socks

- *Como ya he dicho*, no quiero comprar sus calcetines sucios.
- *Como ya le he dicho*, no quiero comprar sus calcetines sucios.
- *Como le acabo de decir*, no quiero comprar sus calcetines sucios.

Here are some differences between each form:

- *Como*: The most neutral form to introduce a previous situation
- *Como ya*: It puts some emphasis to something that has already been introduced.
- *Tal y como*: Totally interchangable with the previous one.

Despite the little differences, the three are interchangable with each other.

I would use *como* as the formal way. Sometimes, to put emphasis might be taken as a provocation. Depends on the situation. So rather use the neutral one.